# Time Variable Gain (TVG) and Signal to Noise Ratio (SNR)

Tags: time, signals, noise

I have some signals of varying lengths that are to be propagated over a distance. I have a Time Variable Gain (TVG) function that compensates for the transmission loss over the range of propagation. I am investigating the SNR of these signals when the TVG is applied, at different ranges. For example, at 10m, 50m and so on. The noise being modeled is White Noise, the co-variance matrix of which is simply the Identity (I) matrix.

While taking into account the TVG, I understand this gain would be applied to both the signal (signals of different lengths) and the noise (white noise) at respective ranges, before we calculate their power and expected value (for noise), and then calculate the ratio.

I am using the simple SNR formula given at the Wikipedia site, the link is given below.

SNR = s^H R_{vv}  s

https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.download?%5Ctext%7BSNR%7D%3D%20s%5EH%20R_%7Bvv%7D%5C%20s

where s is the signal vector, and R_{vv} is the noise co-variance matrix.

How do I add this TVG to the signal and the noise co-variance matrix in this formula to calculate the SNR?

Comment: I have tried to put the SNR formula as an equation and an image but it would not let be post image as I do not have the required reputation level.

Answer (score 0):

The gain would be normalized and applied to the noise covariance matrix. While keeping the overall magnitude of the noise covariance matrix same, the TVG will be applied for the duration of signal and the particular area of the TVG curve you are interested in. That would be mean at what range you are interested in for the TVG and how long is your code to be affected by the TVG.